# Handling post array values and dumping to database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select, post

I have an dynamic POST array like this.

```
    Array
    (
        [56-1] => 9
        [56-2] => 7
        [56-3] => 2
        [56-4] => 3
        [66-1] => 1
        [66-2] => 5
        ..................... so on...........
    }
```

Now what i want to do is - Store the below array values in the table like this

```
        Book ID     Author ID       Rating
        56          1               9
        56          2               7
        56          3               2   
        56          4               3
        66          1               1
        66          2               5
```

Thanks,
Kimz

Comment: What you have done so far?

Comment: muhammad - thanks for your question. i have done nothing with my array values.  i am very new to php and the answers in SOF doesn't meet my requirement.  i have got answer from three bros, and my question is fulfilled. thanks for your instant comment ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please review this code

```
<?php

foreach($yourarray as $key=>$value){
    $skeys=explode('-',$key);
    $bookid=$skeys[0];
    $authorid=$keys[1];
    $ratings=$value;

    $insert="insert into table_name (`Book_ID`,`Author_ID`,`Rating`) values ('$bookid','$authorid','$ratings')";
    mysql_query($insert);
}

?>
```

Comment: using `mysqli_query` will be better, `mysql_*` are deprecated

Comment: he mentioned mysql in tags

Comment: that `mysql` tag is for MySql database ... to access the MySql from PHP, you can use `mysql_*` or `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: tun - will take your words into consideration. thanks for your caring comment.

Answer (score 0):

so, put array into a variable like $arr then:

```
<table><tr> <th> Book ID</th><th> Author ID </th><th>Rating</th></tr>
<?php
foreach($arr as $key =>$val){
$tmp=explode('-',$key );
echo '<tr><td>'.$tmp[0].'</td>'.'<td>'.$tmp[1].'</td>'.'<td>'.$val.'</td></tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: mmm. late to the party. still thanks for your answer. this will help some beginners like me. excellent. this too worked fine. :) thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

For that You need to loop for dynamic array and after that explode.

Code must look like:

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
{
 $keys=explode('-',$key);
 $bookid_array[]=$keys[0];
 $authorid_array[]=$keys[1];
 $rating_array[]=$value;
// Insert Query Here
}
```